# pythonic way to apply function to object multiple times

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to repeatedly sum over varying dimensions of a numpy ndarray eg.

```
#what I've got
sumOverDims = [6 4 2 1]
ndarray = any n-dimensional numpy array

#what I want to do
ndarray.sum(6).sum(4).sum(2).sum(1)
```

how can I do this without an ugly loop?

Comment: Do you mean a list [6, 4, 2, 1] or a list with one item ['6 4 2 1']

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you please explain a bit more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy's `sum` accepts a tuple for the `axis` argument:

```
ndarray.sum(axis=(1,2,4,6))
```

Comment: Dang, I _knew_ there is a builtin for this... +1

Comment: only works for newer numpy versions, above 1.8 I think, but this is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a thing like

```
X.f(e0).f(e1).f(e2).…
```

can be rephrased as

```
reduce(lambda a, b: a.f(b), [ e0, e1, e2, … ], X)
```

or (if you dislike lambdas):

```
def f_(a, b):  return a.f(b)
reduce(f_, [ e0, e1, e2, … ], X)
```

But I'm a bit in doubt if this really makes it more readable and effectively clearer (and thus more Pythonic) than using an iterative loop:

```
result = X
for e in [ e0, e1, e2, … ]:
  result = result.f(e)
return result
```

I guess it boils down to a matter of taste and what you are more used to.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce`. An example with only two dimensions:

```
>>> A = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> reduce(numpy.sum, [1], A)
array([ 6, 15, 24])
>>> reduce(numpy.sum, [1, 0], A)
45
```

The argument to `reduce` is `numpy`'s `sum` function, a list with the dimensions to sum over, and the `numpy` array `A` as the initial element to reduce. The function gets as parameter the (partially summed) `numpy` array and the dimension to sum next.